# How to add syntactic elements to modes with colourizing and correct tabulation

Tags: org-mode, fonts, colors

I am using literate programming in org mode. It adds a new syntactic construction to the language: `<<macro name>>`. Unfortunately, it breaks all the colouring and tabulation after it. For example, this code in `cperl-mode`:

```
my $redis = $c->app->storage('redis');

<<get session id from cookie>>

# checking login, password
my $login = $c->param('login');
```

is rendered as this:

[image]

I tried to colourize the new keyword for cperl mode:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'cperl-mode '(("<<.+?>>" . 'font-lock-variable-name-face)))
```

But it only changes the colour of the first word: as you can see the word "get" is red.

How to set the specific colour for constructions like `<<...>>` and setup correct tabs after it?

Comment: The problem is that Org mode colorizes the code block according the declared language (`perl` in this case I presume), but the `noweb` syntax is not `perl`. It is a stretch already for Org mode to keep the rest of the file colorized according to Org syntax while allowing code blocks to be colorized according to a different mode; mixing yet another mode in there just complicates things further. In short, I don't know how to do it, and I think it is going to be complicated. If you don't get an answer here, you might want to ask on the [Org ML](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-mailing-list.html).

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that in cperl-mode some Perl syntax is treated *beyond* font-lock-mode.  In Perl, "<<" starts a [here-document](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#EOF), in your example taking "get" as the delimiter of the here-document.  cperl-mode acts accordingly and fontifies "get" as the here-doc delimiter.  It also takes the rest of your document as the content of the here-doc and fontifies it as string.  This happens outside of font-lock.  The rest of the <<...>> line is fontified according to your added rule.

You can, sort of, get what you want by fiddling with the syntax of your noweb blocks:

```
#+NAME: [say hello]
#+BEGIN_SRC perl
say "Hello, world";
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC perl :noweb yes :results output
  use 5.024;

  {
      <<[say hello]>>
  }

  say "Hello again!";
#+END_SRC
```

In this example, I started the code block id with a square bracket.  This works for org-mode.  But square brackets are illegal as here-doc delimiters, and cperl-mode respects that.  So, the last line of the source block will be fontified as Perl code.

The extra braces { } around the macro are needed if you want the indentation after your macro to be correct in cperl-mode: The noweb line is an "incomplete statement", so the next line would be interpreted as a continuation line.